# Is there any way I can input a command to delete all Scheduled Tasks with a particular pattern?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, dos

I have a job which creates a scheduled task with a string like this: RunOnce072000, where 072000 is the time the scheduled task was created. I need to delete the scheduled task by command line but cannot figure out a way to use a wildcard to perform the delete.
Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Windows dos prompt, if you can work with "at" (which doesn't associate names with jobs), you will certainly run:

```
at 7:00 "dir foo.txt"
at
```

So perhaps using a for loop would solve your problem:

```
set expected_command=%~1

for /f "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-5" %%a in (`at`) do call:remove_job %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
goto:eof

:remove_job
    if "%1"=="Erreur" shift
    if "%~4"=="%expected_command%" at %1 /delete
goto:eof
```

Take care of the quotes, which "at" removes if there are no arguments to the at-ed command, and of the error state, which is translated (there, in french).